# Is the region $x^2+y^2 \geq 1$ open or closed?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Is the region $x^2+y^2 \geq 1$ open or closed , both open and closed or neither open nor closed?

Closed region is a set of points which contains it's boundary points while open region only contains its interior points excluding boundary points. So what should we take here in the case of infinite set? Is there any definition set for empty and infinite sets?

Comment: That is an inequality, not a region. Inequalities are neither open nor closed.

Comment: You probably mean: "Is the region $ \{ (x,y)\subset \mathbb{R}^2: x^2 + y^2 \geq 1\}\ $open, closed, or neither?"

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes, or both

Comment: It's complement is an open circle, so the region that you defined is closed.

Comment: @V.G $A$ or $B$ does not mean $A$ or $B$ but not both. $A$ or $B$ means, "$A$ or $B$ or both."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a definitely closed set, since $x^2 + y^2 < 1$ is an open set, and your set is the complement set.

Comment: It could be clopen

Comment: It isn't open since $x^2+y^2<1$ is not a closed set.